# 24hour non stop recording in a single file on a 128Gb SDXC?

Tags: file-formats, recording, camcorder, storage

Not sure if I am allowed to ask the following question here or not as it's not clear from the FAQ

I want to record a non stop 24 hour video and wanted to know if the following device can do that?

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/838579-REG/Samsung_HMX_F80BN_XAA_HMX_F80_Flash_Memory_Camcorder.html

This device has a SDXC so I should be able to get more than 24 hours non stop using a 128Gb card right?  So is there a limitation on SDXC cards?  Maybe 4.2Gb per file/video?

Assuming that the camcorder allows recording while plugged into the mains?

Comment: According to the specs, the camera can only handle a 64Gb card which is < 15 hrs of record time at SDXC.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with that particular Samsung camcorder, but I did do some long term recording on an older Samsung camcorder. My camcorder had a time lapse mode that allowed it to capture a frame every minute or so. It would record while plugged in to A/C power. Although the camera used the FAT32 filesystem with 2GB file limits, it was able to span the recording across multiple files. As far as I could tell, the process was seamless.